# Adding a generated .srt into a HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using PHP to generate a .srt file to add into a HTML5 Video, but is not working and its showing this message on console:

```
Resource interpreted as TextTrack but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "../subtitles/Test%20Edit.srt".
```

I am using this JQuery script to make the video work http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/#download, works fine with the example, but not with my .srt file.

I am creating the .srt file with this code:

```
$folder = 'subtitles/';
$filename = $this->get_title() . '.srt';
$fp = fopen($folder.$filename,'w');
$i = 1;
$Query = mysql_query("") or die(mysql_error());

while ($a = mysql_fetch_array($Query)) {
    $subtitle = new Subtitle($a['idSubtitle']);
    $text .= $i . chr(13) . chr(10) . $subtitle->get_start() . 
             ',000 --> ' . $subtitle->get_end() . ',000' . chr(13) . chr(10) . 
             $subtitle->get_text() . chr(13) . chr(10) . chr(13) . chr(10);
    $i++;
}

fwrite($fp,$text);
fclose($fp);
```

It is generating this file:

```
1
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:10,000
Test

2
00:00:12,000 --> 00:00:15,000
Test 2
```

Comment: You're sending the wrong MIME type. I think interpreting an error message is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As Charlotte Dunois said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038371/adding-a-generated-srt-into-a-html5-video#comment51978075_32038371), you're not setting the right MIME type.

There are multiple solutions to this. One would be to load the .srt from a PHP page, that then changes the MIME type using `header()` before any content is served. Another, usually more practical, solution would be to make your web server figure out the correct MIME type by itself, setting the Content-Type header.

If you're using Apache, look into [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html), otherwise look up the documentation for your specific web server.

Comment: I tried make like you said, with a PHP file, but the same error, I changed the header using header('Content-Type:TextTrack; charset=ISO-8859-15');

Comment: Make sure you change the header before you start sending the body (the BOM in UTF-8 counts too). Try monitor the headers on the clientside to see if they're actually being modified with something like [Live HTTP headers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo)